# After running project couple of times, WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, cdi

after I run the project for a couple of times, it began to trow me this error:

"WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped".

but if I close and reopen NetBeans the project work again, for a couple of times...what seems to be the problem?

Comment: post your code snippet please

Comment: And some information - you're running it via netbeans.  What are you running though? a server? Which server?